# Swift thinks my string is an MDL material

Tags: swift3

I'm trying to save data in an image metadata in iOS/Swift3. It does not appear that CG will let you save out custom tags (is that true?) so I JSON encoded my dictionary and put the result as a string into the TIFF tag's ImageDescription. When I load the image and get the metadata back...

```
if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile:oneURL.path), let imgSrc = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data, options as CFDictionary) {
    let allmeta = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imgSrc, 0, options as CFDictionary) as? [String : AnyObject]
```

The `allMeta` contains (among other things):

```
     ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      - key : ImageDescription
      - value : {
  "CameraOrientationW" : 0.1061191,
  "CameraOrientationZ" : -0.01305595,
  "CameraOrientationX" : 0.01319851,
  "CameraOrientationY" : 0.9941801
}
```

Which has the JSON data, yay! So now I simply have to get the TIFF metadata, get the ImageDescription from that, and de-JSON it...

```
let tiffmeta = allmeta?["{TIFF}"]
if let tiffMeta = tiffmeta {
    let descmeta = tiffMeta["ImageDescription"]
    var descdata = descmeta?.data(usingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let descdict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: descdata, options: [])
```

But this will not compile. Xcode puts an error on the `let descdata` line:

`Value of type 'MDLMaterialProperty??' has no member 'data'`

I tried casting it to `String` on the line above, at which point it complains I didn't unwrap the optional MDLMaterialProperty.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Note that dictionary accessors in Swift for a dictionary containing values of `T` return a `T?`.

I suggest you unwrap the optional by using `if let tiffMeta = tiffmeta` rather than checking if `tiffmeta` is nil. Doing so will give you a non-optional type that you can then work with further. You'll also need to use optional-chaining: `descmeta?.data(...)`.

Comment: Useful, but I still have the same problem, it still thinks descmeta is an MDL type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to close this one, this appears to be a problem in the compiler. I made a number of minor changes to the syntax, nothing that had any actual effect on the code, and suddenly it decided the object was indeed a string.